# Custom configuration for /oauth/token end-point

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I use spring-security-oauth2.
I would like to custom configure the /oauth/token end-point.
After registration a new client, I need to use login and password from this client and create a token for him and return this token.
Can I custom configure this /oauth/token endpoint?
Can I return a custom error if I receive incorrect information for this end-point (incorrect login or password)?
Can I put here a client-id and client-secret and don`t enter this in front-end?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

}
}
```